# Noun or adjectives starting with 不

Tags: grammar

Can anyone provide the full list of noun or adjectives which starts with 不.for eg. 不可能. As it is more convenient and better way to write in Japanese rather than to mention its negative form

Comment: I would caution you that just because a compound exists doesn't mean it is the better option than some longer formation that means the same thing.

Comment: Note that, as you can see in the lists provided by the answers, the antonym of a word starting with 不 is not always obtained by removing the 不. E.g. 不足, 不満, 満足; 不運, 幸運.

Answer (score 4):

Using jisho.org, you can get two lists (one for nouns and another for adjectives) by leveraging **search options**. For each case, type into the search placeholder:

> 不* #noun
>
> 不* #adjective

Here you are the results for [nouns](https://jisho.org/search/%E4%B8%8D*%20%23noun) and for [adjectives](https://jisho.org/search/%E4%B8%8D*%20%23adjective). Jisho provides lists of 747 nouns and 277 adjectives starting by 不 respectively. I think that an **or** operator that enables you to combine both results in a single query is not available for jisho.org, it may be for other sources. If you want a list of words that can be *both* nouns **and** adjectives at the same time, you can chain the tags in a single search:

> 不* #noun #adjective

This produces 252 results (see [here](https://jisho.org/search/%E4%B8%8D*%20%23noun%20%23adjective)).

Take into account that using search options in a dictionary is as exhaustive as the dictionary you use. In general, you would get a different result if you try a similar search in a different dictionary. In the case of Jisho, it uses the [JMdict](http://www.edrdg.org/wiki/index.php/JMdict-EDICT_Dictionary_Project) database of words.

Answer (score 3):

You're asking for something on a similar scale to providing a full list of English words that start with "un-". There are a lot. There are a lot that probably don't show up in a dictionary but which would be understood by many Japanese people on the street.

[Here is a search](http://nihongo.monash.edu/cgi-bin/wwwjdic?1MDJ%C9%D4) on WWWJDIC for words with that kanji in the initial position, which is essentially what you asked for. I tried scrolling through to see if there was any indication of how many entries there are, but the best I can say is "more than 100, even if you limit it to common words".

Comment: the OP asks for a list of **nouns or adjectives** starting by 不, but in your results, they appear other kinds of words as well.

Comment: Can anyone provide me the list ? so i can save it and learn from it rather than scrolling everytime in Jisho website

Comment: Jisho.org has an API in case you want to get this list programmatically: https://jisho.org/api/v1/search/

Comment: https://jisho.org/api/v1/search/words?keyword=%E4%B8%8D